# communicating between docker instances of neo4j and express on local machine

Tags: node.js, docker, rest, express, neo4j

ISSUE: I have a docker image running for neo4j and one for express.js. I cant get the docker images to communicate between eachother.

I can run neo4j desktop, start a nodemon server and they will communicate.

SETUP:
NEO4J official docker image

- NEO4J_AUTH none
- PORTS localhost:7474 localhost:7687
- Version neo4j-community-4.3.3-unix.tar.gz

NODEJS Image

- PORTS 0.0.0.0:3000 :::3000
- Version 14.17.5

Express conf

DEV_DB_USER_NAME="neo4j"
DEV_DB_PASSWORD="test"
DEV_DB_URI="neo4j://localhost" //for image purpose for local its bolt://localhost:7687
DEV_DB_SECRET_KEY=""

```
 let driver = neo4j.driver(
        envConf.dbUri,  
        neo4j.auth.basic(envConf.dbUserName, envConf.dbUserName)
        );
```

package.json
"@babel/node": "^7.13.10",
"neo4j-driver": "^4.2.3",

I can remote into the neo4j image through http://localhost:7474/browser/ so its running.

I cannot use the server image to call a local neo4j instance.

when i call the apis in the server image i get these errors

If i use neo4j protocal:

Neo4jError: Could not perform discovery. No routing servers available. Known routing table: RoutingTable[database=default database, expirationTime=0, currentTime=1629484043610, routers=[], readers=[], writers=[]]

If i use bolt protocal:

Neo4jError: Failed to connect to server. Please ensure that your database is listening on the correct host and port and that you have compatible encryption settings both on Neo4j server and driver. Note that the default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0. Caused by: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7687

Ive been scouring the documentation for a while any ideas would be most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the communication by using docker-compose. The problem is that both containers acted as separate networks and i could not find a way to allow the server to communicate with the database. Running docker-compose and building both containers within a single compose network allows communication using the service names.

take note this is tab sensitive!!

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
    lan:

# The different services that make up our "network" of containers
services:
    # Express is our first service
    express:
        container_name: exp_server
        networks:
            - lan
        # The location of dockerfile to build this service
        build: <location of dockerfile>
        # Command to run once the Dockerfile completes building
        command: npm run startdev
        # Volumes, mounting our files to parts of the container
        volumes:
            - .:/src
        # Ports to map, mapping our port 3000, to the port 3000 on the container
        ports: 
            - 3000:3000
        # designating a file with environment variables
        env_file:
            - ./.env.express
    ## Defining the Neo4j Database Service        
    neo:
        container_name: neo4j_server
        networks:
            - lan
        # The image to use
        image: neo4j:latest
        # map the ports so we can check the db server is up
        ports: 
            - "7687:7687"
            - "7474:7474"
        # mounting a named volume to the container to track db data
        volumes:
            - $HOME/neo4j/conf:/conf
            - $HOME/neo4j/data:/data
            - $HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs
            - $HOME/neo4j/plugins:/plugins
        env_file:
            - .env.neo4j
```

with this you can use docker to run both the server and database and anything else while still using change detection rebuilding to develop and even build multiple environment images at the same time. NEAT